Cannot mock external function in Next.js
I have a function called makeApiRequest, the sole purpose of the function is creating REST requests and it is using fetch, I've imported this component in many next.js components like this:
import makeApiRequest from "@/app/helpers/api";
now I want to test those components, I can't seem to do it properly, since many of my components have multiple useEffects and those useEffects are calling makeApiRequest on mulitple routes, so how can I achieve it? I can't seem to mock it properly i even read the docs but all they are doing is using spyOn on the classes and then mocking the instances of a class
i was expecting to assert something like
expect(mockMakeApiRequest).toHaveBeenCalled()
or something similar but it's not even working in my case
